# Java - Convert .NET date to LocalDateTime

Tags: java, date, date-conversion

I´m using a third-part service that returns to me dates in this format:

```
"EndDate":"\/Date(1487615921387-0300)\/","StartDate":"\/Date(1487608721387-0300)\/"
```

My problem is to convert this date to `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime`. I found some answers here, but they were using joda time, so not helpful.

Comment: how should your date look like i think you can use regex to get your date

Comment: it can be a LocalDateTime..

Comment: so your date should  get from this `Date(1487608721387-0300)` so in your String you have two dates i'm wrong?

Comment: right..in my example, there are 2 dates..but you´re correct..

Comment: what does the `0300` mean?

Comment: I´m guessing it´s the Timezone value..

Comment: what fort should look like your date `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` or how exactly ?

Comment: yes...yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm looks good...

Comment: you can check my answer @Rafael Barioni

Comment: @RafaelBarioni No, not a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) but an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). A time zone’s name takes the form of [`continent/region`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal). A time zone is a history of a region’s offsets plus rules for future anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).

Comment: This format should die.  Go back to your third-party service and ask them to use a modern JSON Serializer like JSON.NET and use the ISO8601 default format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok first you should to extract your Dates from your String i use a patttern the idea is simple

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "\"EndDate\":\"\\/Date(1487615921387-0300)\\/\",\"StartDate\":\"\\/Date(1487608721387-0300)\\/\"";
    //Get Long from your String between Date( and )
    String start = "Date(", end = ")";
    String regexString = Pattern.quote(start) + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote(end);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexString);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        //now we get results like this 1487608721387-0300
        res.add(matcher.group(1));
    }

    //You can change the format like you want
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    Date date;
    String[] split;
    for (String s : res) {
        split = s.split("-");
        ///we should to split the String to get the first part 1487608721387
        //then we get Date from this String
        date = new Date(new Long(split[0]));
        //Set time zone to your format i'm not sure if it is correct you can avoid it
        //format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(split[1]));
        //Show your date
        System.out.println(format.format(date));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot @YCF_L..it worked fine...just need to find out if I need to adjust the timezone here..many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to learn the meaning of your input data.

The last part `-0300` is likely an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), a number of hours ahead of or behind [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). I suggest use the format with a colon (`-03:00`) but without is acceptable. You need to know if the plus/minus sign means ahead of or behind UTC. Modern protocols tend to use a *plus* for ahead of UTC and a *minus* for behind, but there are protocols that do the opposite.

Know that an offset is *not* a time zone. A [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) is a history of offsets for a particular region with rules for anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

The first part is likely a count of milliseconds since an [epoch reference date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)). We can *guess* that your epoch is the commonly used first moment of 1970 in UTC (`1970-01-01T00:00:00`). But there are at least [a couple dozen epochs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing) used by various known software systems. Again, you must consult the source of your data.

This particular combination of a count-from-epoch with offset I've seen before. It confounds me as it makes more sense to simply use a count-from-epoch in UTC without an offset. If you want to show a date-time adjusted into a time zone, use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string formats.

I will guess that your input number is a count from epoch in milliseconds in UTC. So we parse it as a `Instant` object. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
String input = "1487615921387-0300";

String inputCount = input.substring ( 0 , 13 ); // zero-based index counting.
long count = Long.parseLong ( inputCount );
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli ( count );
```

We can parse the offset as a [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) object.

```
String inputOffset = input.substring ( 13 );
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.of ( inputOffset );
```

Apply that [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to see the same moment as a [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time) in another offset as an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset ( offset );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/TlEhy2).

> input: 1487615921387-0300
>
> inputMillis: 1487615921387
>
> inputOffset: -0300
>
> count: 1487615921387
>
> instant.toString(): 2017-02-20T18:38:41.387Z
>
> odt.toString(): 2017-02-20T15:38:41.387-03:00

Note the three hour difference between `instant` and `odt`, hours `18` versus `15`, the effect of the offset. Still the **same simultaneous moment**, same point on the timeline, but seen with a different wall-clock time.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: You are correct in your assumptions.  The first part is milliseconds since unix epoch.  The second part is local offset, in +/-hhmm format, with positive values leading east of UTC like the ISO standard.  This stupid format came from the `JavaScriptSerializer` class in .NET, and [is widely recognized as an abomination](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx).  We call it an "ASP.NET JSON Date" [in moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/asp-net-json-date/).  Modern .NET doesn't use it any more.

Comment: @MattJohnson But if the number is a count-from-epoch of UTC, what is the point of the offset? Append an offset to a UTC value adds no value since anyone can apply any offset they want to a UTC value.

Comment: One can still use it to reconstruct a date-time-offset value.  Just that normally we see the date-time portion already converted to local time of the offset - in this case the date-time portion is UTC.